# Screen dims on opening certain applications on Macbook

Tags: 11.10, screen, macbook

I have ubuntu 11.10 installed on an old 2008 macbook. There is an issue of screen dimming that I didnt find anywhere else on the forums.

The issue is that the screen is dimmed when I open certain applications (Firefox, Software Center) and this cannot be readjusted by the physical brightness buttons on the keyboard. I tried a bunch of things on the barely barely visible screen, and had no choice but to restart. This has happened everytime.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This is strange. I'm on 11.06 on a 2008 MacBook as well with no problems with screen dimming. Usually, I run Caffeine to keep my screen from dimming when I'm inactive, but I've never had a problem while I'm active or opening programs. I have upgraded the RAM to 4GB since I bought it; however, I doubt that would affect anything.

Can you post more specifics?

And are you sure it's not just that, while opening programs, you are idle for such a time that your screen dims?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac

The mactel PPA modules needed on ubuntu on mac are mbp-nvidia-bl-dkms (for the LCD dimming support), and pommed (for the keyboard backlight control keys).

```
 sudo apt-get install mbp-nvidia-bl-dkms pommed
```

mbp-nvidia-bl-dkms must be in */etc/modules* file to load. Open the file in an editor with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

And add to the end this line:

```
mbp_nvidia_bl shift=2
```

The *shift* option reduces the dimming range to make it more comfortable. You can tune the value as you want

for more go through this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro5-3/Lucid#Keyboard) from here I found this help 
I think this will help you 
I personally tried this helped me

If this not help see this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Ubuntu_9.04_to_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29)

Comment: My machine is an old macbook (not mbp) is there a version for older machines? (No keyboard backlights either)

Comment: @yayu can u tell me which version u use `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name`

Comment: Macbook 3,1 (character limit)

Comment: @yayu very unfortunate that Mactel Support for this version of MAc is not available see [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages#Mactel%20Product%20Pages) for more on Mactel Community Documentation. here is the list of supported matrix

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a performance issue.
Compiz dims unresponsive applications, and if the situation recurs *when an application is opened*, it most probably is because the application hanged. Firefox and Ubuntu software center at times take time to start on my machine, and the screen is dimmed when i open them, but i recover in few seconds.

 Can you confirm that it happens **only** during opening certain applications? waiting for a while is all that is needed. But still, you will be able to open dash, open terminal with `<ctrl>+<alt>+t` and switch workspaces using `<ctrl>+<alt>+<arrow keys>`.

If **absolutely nothing** works, Then its a different thing. A machine with >=2GB ram should never have such problems. Can you comment with more details? Your RAM??

And try this.
Open firefox or software-center or any other troublesome application and redirect commandline output and errors to a file.
`firefox &>~/mydebuglog`
And if you are forced to restart, after restarting, see if anything was written to ~/mydebuglog. That might help.